# get memory address of pointer variable in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address

How do I get the object which is being pointed at by a pointer variable?

```
IAddress *addPtr = ...;

method (IAddress & add){
    //do something
}
```

How do I pass the `IAddress` to the method?

is this correct?

```
method (&(* addPtr))
```

Comment: `&(*addPtr)` is the same value as `addPtr` as-is (assuming `IAddress` does not override the `&` operator).

Answer (score 4):

There are two questions here so I'll give three answers.

- The address of a pointer variable `p` itelf is given by `&p`.
- The address being pointed at by `p` is given by `p`.
- The *content* of the address being pointed at by `p` is given by `*p`.

This is all rather basic.  Any C++ book/tutorial should cover this.

Comment: EJP: wht is the difference in first and the second bullet

Comment: The difference is that the pointer variable itself has an address, as well as what it is pointing to. Again this is all extremely basic, and this is not the place to learn about it. Try a good C++ tutorial or a book.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `addPtr` is a valid pointer, just dereference it in the function call (which specifies a reference).

```
method(*addPtr)
```